# Trouble rotating image in Android aplication

Tags: java, android, image, rotation, gps

I am currently writing an android application that should rotate an image towards a set location based on the users current location.  I can tell that the set location is setting correctly, and the current location seems to be updating, but instead of rotating the image, the app just zooms in on the image and then does nothing. Any help would really be appreciated!

```
  public double bearing(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double longitude1 = lon1;
    double longitude2 = lon2;
    double latitude1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double latitude2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double longDiff = Math.toRadians(longitude2 - longitude1);
    double y = Math.sin(longDiff) * Math.cos(latitude2);
    double x = Math.cos(latitude1) * Math.sin(latitude2) - Math.sin(latitude1) * Math.cos(latitude2) * Math.cos(longDiff);

    return (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x)) + 360) % 360;
}

private void rotateImageView(ImageView imageView, int drawable, float rotate) {

    // Decode the drawable into a bitmap
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            drawable);

    // Get the width/height of the drawable
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth(), height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

    // Initialize a new Matrix
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // Decide on how much to rotate
    rotate = rotate % 360;

    // Actually rotate the image
    matrix.postRotate(rotate, width, height);

    // recreate the new Bitmap via a couple conditions
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    //BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable( rotatedBitmap );

    //imageView.setImageBitmap( rotatedBitmap );
    imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), rotatedBitmap));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
}

public void onLocationChange() {

    // If we don't have a Location, we break out
    if (currentLocation == null) return;

    double azimuth = bearing(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), baseLocation.getLatitude(), baseLocation.getLongitude());
    double baseAzimuth = azimuth;

    GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(Double
            .valueOf(currentLocation.getLatitude()).floatValue(), Double
            .valueOf(currentLocation.getLongitude()).floatValue(),
            Double.valueOf(currentLocation.getAltitude()).floatValue(),
            System.currentTimeMillis()
    );

    azimuth -= geoField.getDeclination(); // converts magnetic north into true north

    // Store the bearingTo in the bearTo variable
    float bearTo = currentLocation.bearingTo(baseLocation);

    // If the bearTo is smaller than 0, add 360 to get the rotation clockwise.
    if (bearTo < 0) {
        bearTo = bearTo + 360;
    }

    //This is where we choose to point it
    double direction = bearTo - azimuth;

    // If the direction is smaller than 0, add 360 to get the rotation clockwise.
    if (direction < 0) {
        direction = direction + 360;
    }
    float fDir = (float) direction;
    rotateImageView((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow), R.drawable.ic_launcher, fDir);

}


    private Runnable updateTimeChange = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            onLocationChange();
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }


    };
```

Comment: dont call Bitmap.createBitmap, you have a Matrix so call ImageView.setImageMatrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target is greater than 11 then you can try view.setRotation() method:

```
image.setRotation(angle); // this is for your imageview where image is the imageview object
```

From the [developers page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29). getRotation()

> Sets the degrees that the view is rotated around the pivot point. Increasing values result in clockwise rotation.

If you want to setRotation in xml the xml tag is :

```
android:rotation
```

Comment: Could you explain that a little more. I'm a little confused.